# Blender Rendering Image but produce blank in result?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

Please help Y I would get this result in rendering image. For the process it rendering with content but blank at final. Pls check the video for more details.
[image]
Y it would happen and how to fix it?
Million thx!

[Blender 2.79]

Comment: It needs more information. You may send the file for inspection via this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: May be you messed up something in the compositor.

Comment: I've seen this happen by putting negative values in the point light power. See if it renders differently in Eevee vs. Cycles. Of course, try the latest version of Blender.